# An injective map of homogeneous coordinate rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Define $\phi:\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^2$ by $\phi([x_0,x_1])=[x_0^2,x_1^2,x_0x_1]$ and $\phi^{\ast}:S(\phi(\mathbb{P}^1))\to S(\mathbb{P}^1)$ by $\phi^{\ast}(f)=f\circ \phi$.

I would like to show that $\ker \phi^{\ast}$ is the homogeneous ideal of $\phi(\mathbb{P}^1)$. If $g\in \ker\phi^{\ast}$, must $g$ be a homogeneous polynomial?

Comment: The kernel of a graded morphism between graded rings is graded.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion is in the definition of a homogeneous ideal.  To say that an ideal $I$ is homogeneous does *not* mean every element of $I$ is homogeneous.  For instance, $I=(x,y^2)$ is a homogeneous ideal of $k[x,y]$ since it is generated by homogeneous elements, but $x - y^2 \in I$ is not a homogeneous polynomial.